# Placement of dedication in `amsbook` strange - why, and how to change it?

Tags: amsbook

I am using the `amsbook` documentclass (latest version from CTAN), and would like to use `\dedicatory` for a dedication. However, the placement of the dedication is odd: it is placed just below the authors' address, without hardly any space.

Is that normal for a dedication? How to best change this behaviour? (I am aware that `memo-l.cls` puts the dedication in a different spot.)

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\dedicatory{foo bar}
\begin{document}
\title{foo}
\author{Author One}
\email{aasjdfiaejifnieaf@sodifjaiejfiasjfidh.com}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The dedication "foo bar" is oddly close to the email address.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a small compilable example that potential helpers can use to experiment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oops, I had prepared it, but forgotten to copy it in. Done now - thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatting of the dedication in an `amsbook` depends on the particular book series intended.  `memo-l.cls` is a bit of a hybrid, and the `\dedicatory` command used there is not supported for any other series.

The [AMS author handbook for monographs](https://www.ams.org/arc/handbook/handbook-mono.pdf)
says this (on p.12) about the dedication:

> 4.5.  Dedication. The dedication for a monograph is set on a
> separate page. The template provided in the author package includes
> instructions for formatting this page.

The template file for the generic `amsbook` is `chapter-template.tex` and is included in all monograph author packages.  In this file, the manner of coding a dedication is presented thus:

```
...
\maketitle

%    Dedication.  If the dedication is longer than a line or two,
%    remove the centering instructions and the line break.
%\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%    If this book uses the documentclass stml-l or mmono-s, change
%    13.5pc to 10.5pc.
%\vspace*{13.5pc}
%\begin{center}
%  Dedication text (use \\[2pt] for line break if necessary)
%\end{center}
%\cleardoublepage
```

Not as convenient, perhaps, as a single command like `\dedicatory`, but it allows for much greater flexibility.  (And some quite elegant dedication pages have been produced with this outline.)