# Dedicatory text before TOC on amsbook

Tags: amsbook

"Doing a quick survey on a few books, I have seen that there is no consensus. I have books (non-fiction, technical books) that have Acknowledgements before and after the Contents page."

https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/do-acknowledgements-have-to-come-after-the-table-of-contents

I like to have dedicatory text before TOC.

I follow

[Placement of dedication in `amsbook` strange - why, and how to change it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581331/placement-of-dedication-in-amsbook-strange-why-and-how-to-change-it)

and the dedicatory text appears after TOC. It is till before \tableofcontents.

How shall one have dedicatory text before TOC?

This is what I did

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{some text}
\author{some text}


\maketitle


\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{13.5pc}

text 

\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{4}

\include{preface}

\mainmatter
```

These are a list of packages

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage[top = 1.25 in, bottom = 1.25 in, left = 1.25 in, right = 1.25 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

Comment: The usual placement of a dedication with `amsbook` is *before* the TOC.  I've never seen it after the TOC.  So it would be most helpful if you would provide a small compilable example that illustrates what's happening.

Comment: Thank you. I put what I did above.

Comment: That's not quite enough, I fear.  You said that you're using `amsbook`, so I added `\documentclass{amsbook}` at the top, `\end{document}` at the end, and a couple of dummy chapters in between.  When run with pdflatex, the TOC comes after the dedication page and before the preface (which I filled in with a dummy).  So what I think you must be doing is using a package that changes the behavior, and you haven't shown any packages.  (I maintained `amsbook` for a couple of decades, and wrote the documentation, so I'm familiar with the default behavior.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added a list of packages.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the placement of the TOC before the dedication. There are warning messages about the duplication of page numbers, and indeed, setting the page number to 4 where you do does cause that to happen.  Also, there's this warning: "Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode..."  I wouldn't expect `scrextend` (or any `scr` package) to be compatible with `amsbook`.  Finally, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: Then what package shall one use to increase the font size?

Comment: Assuming you mean the size of the dedication text, I wouldn't use a package, but take advantage of the font sizing already available in `amsbook`: `\begingroup \Large text \par \endgroup`.  Grouping is necessary so that the new size doesn't persist into later material. `\par` ensures that appropriate baselines are used, if more than one line is involved.  Even larger sizes are possible: `\LARGE`, `\huge`, and `Huge`.